# Have installed VirtualBox (x86 version) on Mint 17, but there's no menu item for it and I can't run it from a terminal

Tags: virtualbox

The [manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp51637616) says to run VirtualBox from the menu or from a terminal, but neither of these appear to be there, even though the Software Manager clearly says I've got the software installed. How can I run it?

The response from a terminal is:

```
The program 'virtualbox' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt
```

Comment: Try using capital letters, `VirtualBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The version installed does not include a GUI. As the response from the terminal indicates, you'll probably want to install virtualbox-qt for that.